# Inject fake sensor events to Android framework

Tags: android, frameworks, sensors, platform

I would like to know if there is a way to inject sensor events directly into Android framework. 
So I firstly checked the sensor event flow by Thread.dumpstack() in OnSensorChanged.
(SensorActivity is an activity I made for test)

```
java.lang.Throwable: stack dump at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:489)
 at com.test.sensor.SensorActivity.onSensorChanged(SensorActivity.java:64)
 at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent(SystemSensorManager.java:469)
 at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
 at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:138)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

From this, I could know Sensor events are handled by MessageQueue and Looper.

So I thought if i can enqueue fake sensor events messages into MessageQueue, Android framework will handle sensor events as usual.

However I don't know how sensor events message looks like and how to enqueue.

My questions are these:

1. What message should I put into MessageQueue to generate fake sensor events? and how?
2. Is there any other way to inject fake sensor events?

I am modifying source code in Android framework layer(4.4.4), not in App layer.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Tried [android event injector](https://code.google.com/p/android-event-injector/) ?

Comment: @maven I read that and as I know, that is only for touch event.

Answer (score 0):

For injecting fake events into Android framework , the changes should be made to sensor HAL, where the events coming from the kernel side should be stopped.
Further more, the fake events should be send through the HAL to the framework.
This would require you to create APIs for interfacing with the HAL and framework for injection.

For example, you can store the actual sensor events in a file with the following details:

"**Type of sensor,Sensor Delay, X data, Y data, Z data**".

Then create a mode of SensorService to be enabled in injection mode, where the events from the kernel will be stopped.It is here when you will use the previously saved events from sensor to be parsed which will be injected to the sensor HAL to be passed to framework.

Also,if you can stop the actual events from HAL and just pass the fake events to the framework, it should work the same too.